# selecting unique record off two columns

Tags: select

Although ID2 is different in both records (and the name), I need to SELECT just one.  I need something along the lines of MIN(ID1, ID2) - this doesn't work though.  Anyone know which function(s) I can use?

ID1  ID2   Type     Name    Number
150  65    Generic  None    9500
150  78    Generic  Else    9500

Answer (score -1):

Check if [TOP / LIMIT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) can be usefull